# Why are self hosted google fonts not displaying?

Tags: font-face, google-fonts

I am attempting to host my font. The font I am using is **Montserrat** and I downloaded it from **Google Fonts**. I followed the instructions from [here](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/montserrat?subsets=latin), and I also tried using the instructions from [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-self-host-google-fonts--cms-34775)

I still cannot get it to work. Anyone know what it is that I missed?

#### My `style.css`

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local(''), url('/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
    url('/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, 
    iOS */
    url('/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS 
    */
    }

    div {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
```

I am loading the fonts by their URL. I tried to `"preload"` them using the `<link>` tag, but had no success in doing so.

##### My HTML Header

```
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.eot" as="font" type="font/eot" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.svg" as="font" type="font/svg" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-regular.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Comment: did u enclose the contents by <div>xxxx</div> ?

Comment: Quite likely your paths are not correct try "fonts/font.woff2" (remove leading slash) or "./fonts/font.woff2". Check the dev tools network tab - you should see the woff2 files as entries. The preload links are not necessary - remove them until you get the fonts loaded. After everything is working you can prioritize font loading with preload - but you should only load the most essential fonts (e.g monserrat regular woff2). Besides you can safely remove "eot" and "svg" references (only used in ancient internet explorers and old safari versions)